# T-test on two sets of observations from different distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, paired-data

I'm comparing two implementations of an algorithm, and want to find out if one implementation (A) is better than the other (B). I'm mostly interested in the execution time. I have N test cases, each one generates a pair of execution times: ($a_i, b_i$), where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the time taken by A and B, respectively.

Those N test cases are very different, some take less than 1 second, some take more than 5 minutes. Ideally, I would need to run the same test case multiple times and  get the average time of this specific test case. However, due to practical reasons, I can only run each test case once. Is there any statistical test that I can use to determine if implement A is better than B?

Since those N pairs of observations are from different distribution, I cannot directly run a t-test on them. Could I 'normalize' the difference to percentage error: $x_i = (a_i - b_i) / a_i$, then do a single-sample t-test on the derived x_i samples? The assumption is, with the normalization, $x_i$ is of a normal distribution.

Does this sound a reasonable approach? Or any other better way? Thank you a lot!

Comment: This is a complicated problem, because it could be that **A** is faster on the quick test cases, while **B** is faster on the long test cases. If that happens, what do you conclude? Which implementation is better?

Comment: That's a good point. We are more interested in finding out if one implementation is better than the other in the majority of the cases (at least in the first stage). Also based on our prototyping, it should be better regardless of the the slow/fast test cases. We want to confirm this in production.